# Is it possible to conditionally set RemoteIPHeader?

Tags: apache-2.4, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare to manage DNS in a staging setup and often switch between "DNS only" and "Proxied" states. I have Apache listening on port 443 which terminates the ssl and then ProxyPass back to Varnish on port 80. I am using mod_remoteip in Apache 2.4 to ensure the user's real ip is logged. This is easily done as instructed [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029696071-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Option-2-Installing-mod-remoteip-with-Apache) by setting the RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP and making some changes to the log config. All works well so long as I am using the Cloudflare proxy.

However, when I switch to DNS only mode in Cloudflare there is no longer a value in CF-Connecting-IP and my access logs show 127.0.0.1. I can fix this by setting RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For and we are all good again. But I have to change vhost config every time I switch Cloudflare proxy status which I'd like to avoid.

In vhost, I tried to set the RemoteIPHeader inside an  statement which checked to see if CF-Connecting-IP is empty, if so set to X-Forwarded-For, something like this...

```
<if "-n %{HTTP:CF-Connecting-IP}">
   RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
</If>
<Else>
   RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
</Else>
```

... but my config syntax errors with "RemoteIPHeader not allowed here". I assume I can not set RemoteIPHeader inside an if statement.

Is there any way to conditionally set the RemoteIPHeader such that if CF-Connecting-IP is empty, set to X-Forwarded-For? Or another way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

I'm stuck and would appreciate any assistance or ideas.

Comment: CloudFlare sends both headers, so why not just use X-Forwarded-For?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that worked... thanks so much. Are there any pitfalls to not using CF-Connecting-IP ?